# How to persist nifi flowfiles by using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, apache-nifi

right now I'm using nifi and its processors for some streaming stuff (mqtt listener, json evaluating, text replacement, write into db ...).
I'm trying to persist the flowfiles and therefore I did some volume mapping (see below).
But it doesn't work; after restarting the container it seems the flowfiles arent't saved ...

Could anybody give me a hint how to solve that problem?

```
nifi:
image: apache/nifi
restart: on-failure
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
networks:
  - traefik
environment:
  - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8000
volumes:
  - nifi_conf:/opt/nifi/conf
  - nifi_state:/data/nifi/state
  - nifi_db:/opt/nifi/database_repository
  - nifi_flowfile:/opt/nifi/flowfile_repository
  - nifi_content:/opt/nifi/content_repository
  - nifi_provenance:/opt/nifi/provenance_repository 


volumes:
 nifi_provenance:{}
 nifi_flowfile: {}
 nifi_content: {}
 nifi_db: {}
 nifi_state: {}
 nifi_conf: {}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could map docker container folders directly to the host machine like this:

```
services:
  nifi:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/opt/conf
      - ./nifi_state:/data/nifi/state
      ...
```

no additional volume definition required

note that under windows with virtualbox this feature works only in the current user directory.

Comment: For me NiFi can read from such volumes but never write. Do you know how I can give NiFi a write permission to a host folder?

Comment: It writable for me. What OS do you have? If windows, are you using virtual box?

Comment: I am using docker on Ubuntu-1604. It works for templates: ${PWD}/templates:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/conf/templates, however it does not work for the following: flowfile_directory, content_directory, provenance_directory. Have you tried it for those folders?

Answer (score 8):

One update from my side.
Apache Nifi changed their directories after 1.8.0. So you should use the following:

```
volumes:
      - ./nifi_state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
      - ./nifi_db:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
      - ./nifi_flowfile:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
      - ./nifi_content:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
      - ./nifi_provenance:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
```

Answer (score 3):

FINAL EDIT:
After many tests and trials, the only way I have found to persist Nifi with docker swarm has been the following:

Step 1: create nifi_data volume

```sh
$ docker volume create nifi_data
```

Step 2: Start the stack with the following configuration

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.9.2
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 9090
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
      #- NIFI_HOME=/home/nifi
      #- NIFI_LOG_DIR=/home/nifi/logs

    volumes:
      - nifi_data:/home/nifi

volumes:
  nifi_data:
    external: true
```

Step 3: Enter the container

```sh
$ docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

Step 4: Copy the current in the home

```sh
$ cd /opt/nifi/nifi-current
$ cp -r ./* /home/nifi
```

Step 5: Remove Deployed Stack

```sh
docker stack rm nifi
```

Step 6: Deploy stack with the following configuration (just removed the #)

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.9.2
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 9090
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - NIFI_HOME=/home/nifi
      - NIFI_LOG_DIR=/home/nifi/logs

    volumes:
      - nifi_data:/home/nifi

volumes:
  nifi_data:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could only use `docker-compose stop` instead of `docker-compose down` which will not remove your container and thus keeping the volumes mounted.

This means you do not have to do any mapping of volumes and can just use this basic docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  futa-nifi-lsc:
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=9000
    image: apache/nifi:1.8.0
    volumes:
      - ./jdbc_driver:/opt/jdbc_driver
      - ./checkin_files:/opt/checkin_files
      - ./truststore:/opt/truststore
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

For more information read this article [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-45-docker-compose-stop-vs-down).

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  zookeeper:  # the configuration manager
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    ports:
      - 8080 # Unsecured HTTP Web Port
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
      - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=zookeeper:2181
      - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=1 min
    volumes:
      - ./nifi/state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
      - ./nifi/db:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
      - ./nifi/flowfile:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
      - ./nifi/content:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
      - ./nifi/provenance:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
      - ./nifi/logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
```

Comment: Please add an explanation